# erlang substr - no function clause

Tags: erlang

Learning erlang and just a bit confused with what I'm trying to do in the following code:

```
start() ->
   Lst = string:tokens("Hello,How,Are,You!Today",",!"),
   Result = [string:substr(Lst, ".!", len(Lst))],
Result.
```

I get the following error: exception error: no function clause matching string:substr(["Hello","How","Are","You","Today"],".!",5)

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? `lists:substr` is intended to work on a string, a list of characters, but you are calling it in a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

[`string:substr/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#substr-3) takes integers in both its second and third argument:

```
10> [string:substr(Lst, 1, length(Lst))].
[["Hello","How","Are","You","Today"]]
11> [string:substr(Lst, 3, length(Lst))].
[["Are","You","Today"]]
```

You're passing the string `".!"` as the second argument, which is why you're getting a function clause error.